# How do I host a private WinGet Repository on an on-premise server?

Tags: windows

I would like to use [`winget`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) to manage applications in my company, and I would like to setup my own [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/package-manager/winget/source) on one of my on-premise windows servers.

I found a [reference implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource?) which however seems to require using Azure / Cosmos DB which I don't want. I would like to have all of this in IIS / SQL Server, [like you would with chocolatey](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/features/host-packages)

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You add a source, it can be any http/https address (but not currently unc path to a \server\share). The structure needs to follow the same manifest folder structure as Microsoft's github:
https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/master/manifests

[edit] Been trying this myself the past few days. SSL cert is actually required (other articles I read saying http proved to be incorrect). The reference implementation specifies CosmoDB but there is an emulator which can run locally instead of Azure. In fact any NoSQL implementation would probably work such as mongodb/Apache CouchDB. Much of the rest of it requires an Azure tenancy & subscription. It may be possible to self host and manually re-write the VS code provided, but as it currently stands there's no documentation or reference implementation for this, so I don't think it's a practical solution for production use yet sadly. We're holding off and sticking with chocolatey (which supports http(s) and UNC fileshare paths etc) until this situation improves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [winget.Pro](https://winget.pro), an open source private winget repository implementation that does not require Azure. It can run in Docker or on a Linux VPS. At the moment, it does not support IIS / SQL Server. Instead, it stores version information in a SQLite database and files locally or on S3-compatible storage.